# Binary and hexadecimal facts and thoughts

Tags: binary, hex

Binary has become a trope among society, yet no one understands it. Computers use them to run vast Operating systems and do complex calculations and binary arithmetic all of the time, hundreds of millions and even billions of little sparks pass through a tiny piece of metal in seconds, yet no one can fathom the depth and magnitude of all of those sparks and arcs that make the magic happen.

But remember that at one point, people had to actually code and decode in this boolean language to be able to make the microprocessor so they could abstract to hexadecimal and assembly language, thus making everyone's lives easier, and finally move on from massive mainframe computers and punchcards.

This will serve as a collection of interesting facts, thoughts, epiphanies and theories on binary and its big brother hexadecimal. Anyone can add to it, but this is going to be a self-answered "FAQ", according to Stack Overflow.

---

Anyways, I hope everyone that reads this finds something interesting that could perhaps help them in anything from web design to assembly language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Understanding binary

This is something that you simply know, or don't know. Fortunately, I happen to understand this quite clearly, so let's start with encoding to and from binary. Then I can talk about hexadecimal and all that jazz hopefully without seeming like I'm speaking a different language. *¿Usted sabe, cuando usted no puede entender lo que alguien está diciendo?*

We will use the byte as the example, since this is clearly the most used iteration of binary in computing and storage.

So without further ado

**From binary**

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
h g f e d c b a

a - 2^0, or 1
b - 2^1, or 2
c - 2^2, or 4
d - 2^3, or 8
e - 2^4, or 16
f - 2^5, or 32
g - 2^6, or 64
h - 2^7, or 128
```

This goes on forever, of course.

The way it is decoded is that the number for each place value is multiplied by the value of the number at the place value, and then added on and on.

Like, for example, in base 10:

```
1 302 = 1*10^3 + 3*10^2 + 0*10^1 + 2*10^0 = 1000 + 300 + 00 + 2 = 1 302
```

Same applies in base 2, except you can omit the multiplying part since there are only two possible values, `0` and `1`. Meaning you can either *add* that power of 2, or *not* add that power of 2.

```
01000001 = 0+64+0+0+0+0+0+1 = 64+1 = 65
11111111 = 128+64+32+16+8+4+2+1 = 255
```

**To Binary**

The same works in reverse, just subtract the largest possible power of 2 from the number until you've broken the number down to all of its components:

```
97 = 64+32+1 = 01100001
```

This can get tricky sometimes.

**But wait, all of these, when added together, only go up to 255, I thought 256 was the magic number!**

Well first of all, remember that computers start from `0`, not from `1` like us humans do.

Second of all, 256 *is* the magic number, it's just that `256` is specifically 2^8, or `1 0000 0000`.

`255`, the 256th value when starting from 0, is the maximum address value of a byte, or `1111 1111`.

---

### Binary and hexadecimal

Ever wondered why hexadecimal is used? Why not pentadecimal? Why not sexagesimal? Why not, dare I say, decimal!?

The answer is because 16, the base of hexadecimal, is exactly equal to 2^4, meaning that you can take any bytestream, cut it into segments of 4, and represent it as a hexadecimal number 4 times smaller. Another side effect is that Hexadecimal, being an exact power of binary, is a lot more straightforward and practical to convert between binary than it is to convert between decimal and binary.

```
Example: 01000001, which is the ASCII/Unicode standard code for the letter 'A'

Decimal: 01000001 = 2^0*1 + 2^1*0 + 2^2*0 + 2^3*0 + 2^4*0 + 2^5*0 + 2^6*1 + 2^7*0 = 65

Hexadecimal: 01000001 = 0100 (4) 0001 (1) = 41
```

For example, the ASCII/Unicode code for `A` is `01000001`, or `0x41`. Conversion is very straightforward. It is because of this that it was made practical to program in asm.

Imagine, for a second, how painful assembly coding would be if instead of pointing to address spaces that look like `FF0E`, you were pointing to address spaces that look liked `1111111100001110`.

---

### You can count to 1023 with your hands

This, I've actually found to be useful. I've been trying to use it to asses its usability vs our traditional unary counting system, and have found that the ability to count to 31 on one hand is very useful in a lot of situations. I am not the only one who's discovered this.

For a basic explanation:

```
Right Thumb     = 2^0 (1)
Right Index     = 2^1 (2)
Right Middle    = 2^2 (4)
Right Ring      = 2^3 (8)
Right Little    = 2^4 (16)

The right hand alone can count to 31

The pattern can be continued to the left hand to count all the way to 1023, which is more than you'll ever need!

Left Little     = 2^5 (32)
Left Ring       = 2^6 (64)
Left Middle     = 2^7 (128)
Left Index      = 2^8 (256)
Left Thumb      = 2^9 (512)
```

You might want to be discreet with 4, 5, and 6, though.

For more information on this, Wikipedia has an [article on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_binary), although I will warn that their gallery is very disorganized and doesn't do well to showcase a lot of positions.

---

### ASCII/Unicode

Okay, for just a minute, look at an ASCII or Unicode table and look at the numbers next to the letters. Notice how `A` is at 65, and `a` is at 97. This makes zero sense, right? Now look at it again, but pay special attention to the hexadecimal columns for each row. Notice that `A` is at 41, and `a` is at 61. This is very much on purpose.

One thing I found very clever was how ASCII actually lined up the alphabet characters.

*ahem*

```
1 => 0011 0001 or 0x31
A => 0100 0001 or 0x41
a => 0110 0001 or 0x61
```

That's right, the capital letters start at `41` for A, and A is the first letter of the alphabet. This means that it's actually really easy to represent a character in hexadecimal. If you want `E`, then add 5 to the capital base, `5 + 40 => 0x45`. If you want `f`, then do the same, but with 60 as the base, `6 + 60 => 0x66`. Additionally, the numbers have a base as well, `30` (which is 0), so for `7`, you would do the same: `7 + 30 => 0x37`.

Before realizing this, I always wondered, "why in the world would they stuff a bunch of symbols between the sets?". The reason is so that A lands at 0x41, a lands at 0x61, and 1 lands at 0x31.

**A detailed description of the table**

```
0000 - 001F - Control characters
0020 - 002F - Symbols
0030 - 0039 - Arabic Numbers 0-9
003A - 0040 - Symbols
0041 - 005A - Capital Latin Letters A-Z
005B - 0060 - Symbols
0061 - 007A - Lowercase Latin Letters a-z
007B - 007E - Symbols
007F - 00A0 - Control Characters, ending with the oft-used `&nsbp;` character (`0x00A0`)
```

There's more to this, though.

---

### Hexadecimal URIs

We all know that `%20` means space. But how many people actually know *why* `%20` means space? Isn't space's ASCII keycode 32? Should't it be `%32`?

Well, it turns out that this also ties into the Hexadecimal ASCII cleverness.

The simple answer is that 20 is the hexadecimal number for space, so `%20` is the URL-encoded code for space. How can this be proven? Go to `http://google.com/?q=%41%42%43%44%45%46%47%20%48%20%49%20%47%4F%54%20%4D%59%20%47%45%44`. If what I am saying is true and the Unicode table I used is accurate, you should arrive at google's home page with "ABCDEFG H I GOT MY GED" automatically inserted in the search bar. (Note: I did not actually get a GED, haha)

---

### Windows Alt Codes

Machines running Windows have the ability to write special symbols using "Alt Codes". Instead of using hexadecimal, however, Microsoft used Decimal, probably because there are no `A-F` keys on a right-hand keypad.

While most of the symbols from 0-255 are seemingly completely random and not compliant with Unicode standards (of course), you *can*, for example, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and type:

<kbd>6</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> for `A`

<kbd>9</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> for `a`

So, in theory, shouldn't <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> produce a "Start of Header" control character?

Nooope! It's a smiley face, which is actually `0x263A`, which means <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> should produce it, not <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>. Although, maybe it *does*.

Edit: I looked it up, and yes, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> does in fact generate this: `☺`, the exact same symbol that's generated if you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>. So bravo to Microsoft for consistency.

---

### Binary arithmetic

It also turns out that the arithmetic that we learned through 1st-4th grade applies to binary as well. Wikipedia, being the colossal monument of knowledge that it is, has an [article on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Binary_arithmetic) as well.

Basically, you know how you can add `150` and `1509` like so:

```
1509
+150
____
1659
```

or, like this, if you took algebra and found balancing more convenient:

```
1509 + 150 => 1609 + 50 => 1600 + 59 => 1659
```

In binary, the same rules apply:

```
 0101 (5)
+1010 (10)
 ____ (=)
 1111 (15)
```

Of course, for more information, Wikipedia's article covers this.

---

### HTML Color Codes

Wikipedia has a brief mentioning of this in their hexadecimal article, but I feel it is very useful, so I will talk about this, too.

An HTML color code looks like this, `#xxxxxx`. It turns out that a lot of people do not know how to read or write Hex color codes, so they use an HTML color picker to make the colors of their website, and end up with crazy looking CSS code like

```
div.loginForm{
    background:#03BFD7;
    . . .
}
```

I don't know about other people, but this drives me crazy, because when it comes to colors, the difference between `04` and `00` in a permutation of 256 possible values is negligible. Most of the time, you can estimate based on whether the second number is above or below 7.

Here's how color codes work:

```
# 00 00 00
^ ^  ^  ^
1 2  3  4

1 - Denotes a color
2 - the first byte, which represents red
3 - the second byte, which represents green
4 - the third byte, which represents blue
```

Recognize the pattern? Of course: `rgb`.

Using this, and looking back at the example, it is possible to round the bytes; trust me, the human eyes can barely, if at all, recognize a difference.

```
The first byte is 03. The ones digit is below 7, therefore we round down, 00.

The second byte is BF. The ones digit if far above 7, therefore we round up, C0.

The third byte is D7. The ones digit is equal to 7, therefore we round up, E0.

Add them back together, and you get #00C0E0
```

Another cool thing is that you can shorten hex codes, meaning a code like our rounded example means the same exact thing as if you simply ignored the ones digits for each byte.

In other words, `#00C0E0 = #0CE`.

```
div.loginForm{
    background:#0CE;
    . . .
}
```

Ah! Much better.

---

Anyways, I hope the explanations and thoughts I posted were helpful to anyone reading this, and happy coding!